# how to check user's data with regular expression?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a form with some controls. I didn't use validations in visual studio toolbox, In fact I have defined validations for these controls using java script . one of these validations is Regular Expression .
 how to check user's data with this regular expression?

```
for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    if (patterns[i] != "") {
        val = document.get ElementById ('cntrl'+i).value;
        ptrn = patterns[i];
        if (!ptrn.test(val)) {
            msg += "bad format. \n";
            j = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I test this code by Firebug, but it exits from second if loop in first time.

Comment: Can we see some code, such as what you've tried, what you want to validate and the _RegExp_ you're trying to use?

Comment: Make sure to validate on the server-side, too. Validating with JavaScript should only be used for the user's convenience; JavaScript can be easily turned off, and you still need to make sure your server is safe.

Comment: @voithos: how to validate on server side?

Comment: Just perform the same validation checks after the form submits, in ASP.NET

Comment: @voithos:before submitting, I check data using javascript. your meaning is that I check them after submitting and by c#?

Comment: @Angel: [Exactly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076927/why-do-we-need-server-side-as-well-as-client-side-validation-for-web-application).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var pattern = /^\d{3}[-]\d{4}$/;
var input = '867-5309';

if (input.match(pattern))
{
  console.log("Jenny I've got your number.");
}

--output:--
Jenny I've got your number
```