# Is server side validation and jQuery Validation both necessary today?

Tags: php, jquery, html, validation, server-side-validation

I have complete jQuery validate() validations accross all my fields in my forms, complex and simple validation even custom methods.

The question I ask now considering it is 2015 and most browsers support javascript and have it enabled by default.

How necessary is server-side validation today, and is it even worth it? If so, what is the latest ideal way to do it as I know a few ways such as checking all the post data and outputting a error on submit, this was going back a few years now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076927/why-do-we-need-server-side-as-well-as-client-side-validation-for-web-application

check the accepted answer here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**YES.**

1. Javascript in browser can be disabled
2. User can edit the javascript code in the browser(Not reliable)
3. Client side validations save network requests. Minimizes load on server. If error, the request goes to server and then respond back with error.
4. Better User Experience